# Java Client - Go Http Mux Server - Parameter empty on go method

Tags: java, rest, http, go, httpclient

I'v got a GO Lang REST API that works normally when I call it from Postman. But, when I try to call a `DELETE` method with `HttpURLConnection` parameters are not received by my method.

Request:

```
_url = new URL(_urlBase+method);
_http = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
_http.setRequestMethod(requestType);
_http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");    
if ((requestType.toUpperCase().equals("POST")) || (requestType.toUpperCase().equals("DELETE"))) 
{
    _http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); 

    byte[] postData = params.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
    int    postDataLength = postData.length;

    _http.setDoOutput( true );
    _http.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    _http.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    _http.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
    _http.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
    _http.setUseCaches( false );

    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( _http.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.write( postData );
    }
}

if (_http.getResponseCode() != 200) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + _http.getResponseCode());
}
```

PS: I've got a three REST APIs in test at this moment. This method just don't pass parameters for GO Lang, using `MUX`. On Scala and Rails is working fine.

PS: On Go I'm getting parameter from `http.Request.FormValue(field)`.

Go Routes:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/get", get).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/putCity/{city}", putCity).Methods("PUT")
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/updateCity", updateCity).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/deleteCity", deleteCity).Methods("DELETE")
http.ListenAndServe(":12345", r)
```

Method getting parameter:

```
func deleteCity(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {   
    var city string = r.FormValue("city")
}
```

Thanks for trying to help guys! Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=38476:38522#L1154) of golang's `http.Request.ParseForm()`, it seems that the form data is not parsed for `DELETE` requests.

I'd suggest using the identifier of the city to be deleted as request parameter in the URL:

```
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/deleteCity/{city}", deleteCity).Methods("DELETE")
```

While you're at it, you could also refactor the whole definition of the routes to be more consistent with standard REST API design patterns, e.g.,

```
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/cities/", getCities).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/cities/{city}", getCity).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/cities/{city}", createCity).Methods("POST") // with body
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/cities/{city}", updateCity).Methods("PUT") // with body
r.HandleFunc("/Rest/cities/{city}", deleteCity).Methods("DELETE")
```

You can use the following snippet to inspect the request. Please note that this should only used for testing purposes and not in a production environment:

```
func deleteCity(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("deleteCity handler called")
    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprint(err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("%q\n", dump)
    var city string = r.FormValue("city")
    log.Printf("city: %q\n", city)
}
```

Comment: Hi @fhe, first of all thank you for spending some time to help me!
In fact, I've already tried to apply your suggest before creating this post.
But, when I did it, I was getting params from mux.Vars(httpRequest) and It wasn't getting parameters too.
The interesting thing is that when I make this requestion from postman app, Go Server is able to get parameters on both way. That's made me thought I've got a JAVA request problem...

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the different results between Postman and your Java client? I've checked this again using your code (with Postman and Java) and there is no form value returned from `FormValue()` in case of a DELETE request. I've added a code snippet to inspect the actual request vs. the form value to my answer above.

Comment: Just as a side note, you're setting the `Accept`request property twice in your Java client code :)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't pay attention for accept into If... I'll take It out... I'll try use parâmetro on URL once and tell you result. Thanks for all man...